# Proper formal synonyms for "blessed"

Tags: word-usage, formality

I am currently using the word "**blessed**" in writing a STEM paper (to be published). The usage would be something like "Devices of this type are often blessed with more reliability", or, "Function of this class are often blessed with smoothness". The word "blessed" used here sounds somewhat improper to me, even sounding a bit humorous (?). I can try to reword it and avoid using "blessed" here, but I often find myself in such a situation where a proper formal synonym of "blessed" would be perfect. After searching in some thesauruses, I am still not sure about it.

Comment: Could you use *noted for* instead of *blessed with*?

Comment: "Devices of this type are typically more reliable."

Comment: `noted for` still sounds quite different from what I want from `blessed with`.

Comment: "Endowed with" would work, although that might be a little formal for your context. It would, however, have a very similar meaning, without the religious overtones.

Comment: Why not just say “Devices of this type are more reliable”? “Blessed” suggests an attribute conferred by an outside power, possibly as a gift.

Comment: "Bestowed" or "endowed".

Comment: "Endowed" seems a good option.

Comment: '... often offer ...' is a less unnatural-sounding personification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would personally use *built*, if you want something closer to *blessed*, the most practical word I can think of that still has some of that meaning is [**favoured**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/favored) (or *favored*, depending on the regional spelling):

> **1** : having an appearance or features of a particular kind
> **2** : endowed with special advantages or gifts

Its use in the example sentences follows:

- Devices of this type are often *favoured* with more reliability.
- Functions of this class are often *favoured* with smoothness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the word `blessed`is that it is often used sarcastic for bad behavior in non-religious context:
https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=blessed

The word "Devices of this type are often blessed with more reliability" sounds contradictory, when you dont give numbers or the relation in what they are reliable.
The pun here is also that a non-reliable device can be called broken, since a device has the functionality as purpose.

To me there is no good or well-meaning word for a non-functional device.

Comment: No sarcasm intended actually. I am trying to convey some meaning like "being fortunate to have a special good quality".

Answer (score 0):

Fortunate (Oxford Languages)

> favored by or involving good luck or fortune; lucky.

Privileged (Oxford Languages)

> having special rights, advantages, or immunities.

> having the rare opportunity to do something that brings particular pleasure.